# Dates out of order

Tags: python, python-2.7, calendar

Why does it starts with december? And `1 1` repeats at the end. Whats the more Pythonic way to iterate over all days in a given year (with handling the leap year)?

```
import calendar

a = calendar.Calendar(0)
for b in range(1,13):
    for x in a.itermonthdates(2016,b):
        print x.month, x.day
```

Output:

```
12 28
12 29
12 30
12 31
1 1
1 2
1 3
..
..
..
```

Full Output:

http://pastebin.com/nnP4ADQK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`itermonthdates`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.Calendar.itermonthdates) returns complete weeks:

> **itermonthdates(year, month)**
>   Return an iterator for the month month (1–12) in the year year. This iterator will return all days (as datetime.date objects) for the month and all days before the start of the month or after the end of the month that are required to get a complete week.

You could just reject the dates where year is not 2016:

```
import calendar

a = calendar.Calendar(0)
g = (x for b in xrange(1, 13) for x in a.itermonthdates(2016, b) if x.year == 2016)
print next(g)
```

Output:

```
2016-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

`itermonthdates` 
returns all weeks which includes days of month. So check should be done for all months.

```
import calendar 
a = calendar.Calendar(0)
for b in range(1,13):
    for x in a.itermonthdates(2017,b):
        if x.month==b:
            print x #x.month, x.day
```